# What is the meaning of parentheses in Haskell type signatures?

Tags: haskell, types, parentheses

Take the type signature of `fmap` (the `Functor` method) as an example:

```hs
(a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

How is that different from the following type signature?

```hs
a -> b -> f a -> f b
```

Is there even a difference between those two type signatures?

Comment: How are the question in the text and the question in the title related? Parentheses in type signatures do *not* denote special semantics, they are for precedence, just like everywhere else in Haskell, which is why the two snippets are *not* equivalent.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I agree that the two questions are not *equivalent* -- and in fact have different answers -- but I'm surprised that you find them *unrelated*. They're both about the meaning of parentheses in type signatures; a "yes" answer to the question in the title would probably entail a "yes" answer to the question in the text; and a good answer to either question would probably implicitly (or even explicitly) answer the other.

Comment: Parentheses in type signatures denote precedence, just like in terms. Precedence is purely a *syntactic* property, it has no semantic significance. So, parentheses in type signatures are neither special nor semantics, and *that* is why the two snippets are not equivalent, just like `a + b * c` and `(a + b) * c` are not equivalent, also because of syntactic precedence and not because of semantics.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference, because [the `->` type constructor is *right-associative*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-630004.1). In other words,

```hs
a -> b -> f a -> f b
```

is equivalent to

```hs
a -> (b -> (f a -> f b))
```

This type signature denotes a function that takes a parameter of type `a` and returns a function, which itself takes a parameter of type `b` and returns a function, which itself takes a parameter of type `f a` and returns a value of type `f b`.

On the other hand,

```hs
(a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

denotes a function that takes a parameter of type `a -> b` (i.e. a function that takes a parameter of type `a` and returns a value of type `b`) and returns a function, which itself takes a parameter of type `f a` and returns a value of type `f b`.

Here is a contrived example that illustrates the difference between the two type signatures:

```hs
f :: (Int -> Bool) -> [Int] -> [Bool]
f = map

g :: Int -> Bool -> [Int] -> [Bool]
g n b = map (\n' -> (n' == n) == b)

λ> let ns = [42, 13, 42, 17]

λ> f (== 42) ns
[True,False,True,False]

λ> g 42 True ns
[True,False,True,False]

λ> g 42 False ns
[False,True,False,True]
```

Answer (score 13):

Yes,

```
(a -> b) -> ...
```

means "given a function which takes a to b ...". While, this

```
a -> b -> ...
```

means "given some a and some b..."

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the `(a -> b)` means one argument which is a function with signature `a -> b`, whereas `a -> b -> ...` means two arguments.